# How to create a custom delete button?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I'm using Yii 2 Framework. I have my data displayed in [GridView](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview) and each row has a delete button. Here's my code:

```php
'content'=>function($data) {
return Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> Bekor qilish', ['delete'], ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'data-method'=>'post']);
```

I want post actionDelete to be fired when user clicks the button. My code isn't working, I'm getting:

> 400: Missing required parameters: id.

I found the following code that I believe from Yii 1:

```php
    echo CHtml::link("Delete", '#', array('submit'=>array('post/delete', "id"=>$data->id), 'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete?'));
```

Is there any similar solution in Yii 2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,

'columns' => [
    'Sample_Column1',
    'Sample_Column2',
        ['header' => 'Actions',
        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => '{new_action}',
        'buttons' => [
            'new_action' => function ($url) {
                return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>', $url, [
                            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Delete'),
                            'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to delete?'),
                            'data-method' => 'post', 'data-pjax' => '0',
                ]);
            }
        ], 'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model) {
            if ($action === 'new_action') {
                $url = Url::to(['your_controller/your_delete_action', 'id' => $model->Some_id_from_your_db]);
                return $url;
            }
        }
    ],
],
]);
```

1. Make sure you set a delete action in your controller and replace the `'your_controller/your_delete_action'`
2. Replace the `Some_id_from_your_db` to the element id you want to delete from your db. Hope it helps. Cheers.

Edit: The `'Sample_Column1', 'Sample_Column2',` is just for your reference because you didn't mention your table details. Therefore edit it accordingly.